# In data(kyphosis) : data set ‘kyphosis’ not found

Tags: r

I tried to run an example R script for gam, where you need to start with the line data(kyphosis). I tried to run this line but got the warning message:

```
data(kyphosis)
```

> Warning message: In data(kyphosis) : data set ‘kyphosis’ not found

My session info is as follows:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  plyr_1.8.3    tools_3.3.0   Rcpp_0.12.5   stringi_1.0-1 stringr_1.0.0
```

I would very much like to know to what has gone wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

As data "kyphosis" comes with `gam` library, you need to load your library first before you can attach the data.

```
library(gam); data("kyphosis")

head(kyphosis)
  Kyphosis Age Number Start
1   absent  71      3     5
2   absent 158      3    14
3  present 128      4     5
4   absent   2      5     1
5   absent   1      4    15
6   absent   1      2    16
```

Comment: or `data("kyphosis",package="gam")` (if you don't want to load the <s>library</s> package for some reason)